# How to change where something scrolls to based on the current position on the page?

Tags: jquery, css

Sorry if my question is unclear, I had a hard time trying to phrase it properly.

I have a series of 100% width gallery-like images with some side arrows on top to navigate through them. I'm having a hard time trying to think of a method that would allow me to change where the arrows scroll to depending on what image is currently on the screen.

I basically need something like this:

if (element2) is currently taking up 100% of the viewport, have (leftarrow) go to (element1) and have (rightarrow) go to (element3)

I've tried to sort of formulate what this would entail, something like:

1. check if (element2) is taking up 100% of the viewport -- not sure if you can do this
2. if (element2) taking up 100% of the viewport == true, change the href of (leftarrow) to (element1) -- I assume you can do this with some sort of innerHTML thing
3. if (element2) taking up 100% of the viewport == true, change the href of (rightarrow) to (element3)

I'm a little overwhelmed. Can someone point me in the right direction? Or let me know if this method would even work? Any help would be appreciated! :-)

edit: updated with some code

Here's how I currently have the side arrows to (sort of) function:

```
$('.sidearrowleft').click(function () {
    $.scrollTo('#img1', 800);
});

$('.sidearrowright').click(function () {
    $.scrollTo('#img2', 800);
});
```

I'm using the [scrollTO](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) plugin from Ariel Flesler to go to my div containing the image.

So right now it functions correctly for just two images, but I need some way of setting a value to the arrows depending on what image the window is currently on so I can have it function for more than just two images, if that's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping track of currently shown image in a variable will save you a lot of nerves.

Something like: `var currentImage = 1;`. Then when you click the next arrow, you scroll to the image 2 and also increment the value of `currentImage`, and do the opposite for the previous arrow (you decide whether the image to the left of the first one will be the last one in the set, or you'll just disable the previous arrow when you're on the first image (and the next arrow when you're on the last, of course)).

There's really no need to torture yourself (and the browser) with all the calculation code for something you can so easily have available in a variable.

UPDATE

So here's how I would do it:

```
var currentImage = 1; // default value, the first image is shown

$('.sidearrowleft').click(function () {
    if (currentImage == 1)
        return; // prevent the scroll when you're on the first image
    currentImage--; // decrement the value
    $.scrollTo('#img' + currentImage, 800);
});

$('.sidearrowright').click(function () {
    if (currentImage == totalImages) // totalImages is a variable containing the total number of images
        return; // prevent the scroll when you're on the last image
    currentImage++; // increment the value
    $.scrollTo('#img' + currentImage, 800);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll fiddle around with this and see if I can get it to work :-) Do you have any examples of how to increment the value of currentImage? I'm a little confused about that part

Comment: Sure, tell me first how do you handle your arrow click code. Or even better, show some code.

Comment: Alright I updated my post with what I have so far. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok this looks like it will work perfectly but I'm just a little confused about how to actually get the currentImage variable to actually correlate to the divs that I have in my css. Do I like, throw them in a variable and set them equal to currentImage? Sorry I'm a bit of a noob to jquery :(

Comment: Oh wait I think I understand. I just set each div containing my image to a numeric value from 1 - totalImages?

Comment: This part `'#img' + currentImage` just concats the string, so in case currentImage is 2, it will produce `#img2`. If you don't want to give separate id to each image, you can give them the same class, and then find them with something like: `$('.imageClassName').eq(currentImage-1)`... it needs -1 because JS is zero-based - the first image has the index of 0 and we set the default value of currentImage to 1

Comment: No, you need to set the id of each div containing an image to `imgX`, where X is the order number (1, 2, 3...)

Comment: Awesome, this will work perfectly. Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it :-) I understand how it works now :D